# Что лучше во вложенных циклах: for или foreach?

Tags: php, циклы

Что лучше `for` или `foreach` во вложенных циклах с проверкой различных условий?
`foreach` смотрится лаконичней, а `for` мне кажется работает быстрее. Дайте совет профессионала?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думается мне, на тех размерах массива, где это будет заметно, действия внутри цикла по тормозам затмят разницу между конструкциями полностью. Используйте то, что удобнее.

```
for(;;) //, когда требуется активная работа с индексами
foreach( as ) //, когда со значениями, либо когда индексы ассоциативные
array_walk() // для корректировки массива.
```

Answer (score 6):

Не задумывайтесь о мелких оптимизациях. Используйте то, что на ваш взгляд лучше отражает вашу мысль. Если вы думаете "я хочу обойти все элементы", может быть, foreach -- лучший выбор.

Оптимизируйте только если (1) ваша программа выполняется слишком медленно, и (2) вы установили, что именно этот цикл создаёт проблему.

"Предварительная оптимизация -- источник всех бед", как сказал дедушка Кнут.

Comment: @VladD а я в сотый раз повторю - что оптимизацией нужно заниматься с самого начала, еще когда код только в голове крутиться. Со временем это войдет в привычку и сэкономит много сил и нервов. Кто же любит возвращаться к старому, давно забытому коду? Да никто.

Comment: @lampa: не могу согласиться на все 100%. Код должен быть чистым и легко понятным. Сравните обычную реализацию копирования памяти и [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). Хотя нестандартная реализация и предоставляет некоторый выигрыш по производительности, я бы не хотел видеть подобный код в обычном теле программы. Другой опцией оптимизации было бы вручную заинлайнить все функции -- мы теряем ясность кода, но зато выигрываем несколько микросекунд на сэкономленных вызовах. И так далее.

Comment: @lampa: и код долженм быть настолько хорош и кристально чист, что понять и поправить его даже через год не составляет никакого труда. В противном случае это всё равно плохой код, и его надо переписать.

Comment: Суровая битва комментариев к ответу на сакраментальный вопрос: for vs foreach для небольшого количества элементов. Абстрагируясь от времени на интерпретацию php-кода.

Comment: @alexlz: это ж не битва, это так, предверительная пристрелка :) вопрос на самом деле более высокого уровня: где и когда начинать оптимизацию, насколько можно жертововать семантикой в угоду эффективности.

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2009/12/blog-post_08.html) тоже неплохо о предварительной оптимизации.

Comment: @avp: о, SergeyT крут, да :) я намеренно не привёл полную цитату, чтобы подчеркнуть мысль, а то многие почему-то считают, что именно у них здесь и сейчас всегда вот эти самые 3%. (На этот случай мой второй абзац в ответе.)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно `for` для индексных массивов, а `foreach` для ассоциативных.

Comment: А я считал, что в php все массивы ассоциативные. А где можно прочитать про индексные массивы (1). Туда элемент с символьным ключом точно не запишется? (2)

Comment: @alexlz ну это я так считаю)

В принципе массив вида: 

`

    $array = array();
    $array[] = 1;
    $array[] = 2;
`

Можно считать индексным. Через for работать с ним гораздо удобнее.